# Настройки CONFIG_HZ в ядре Linux

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

Дано: debian amd64 7.8 с ядром 3.2, запущен в режиме консоли, 2 процессора по 6 ядер каждый. Обслуживает несколько нагруженных игровых серверов (valve) 32битной архитектуры.

Вопрос: какими должны быть настройки ядра в разделе CONFIG_HZ для подобной нагрузки? Вопрос сохранения электроэнергии не интересует вообще. Требуется максимально быстрая отзывчивая система.

Вопрос2: есть ли разница между настройками HZ у ядра 3.2 и ядра 4?

Для справки ниже приведен процесс настройки ядра 2.6

```html
param.h and jiffies.h 


vi include/asm-i386/param.h

Code
#ifndef _ASMi386_PARAM_H
#define _ASMi386_PARAM_H

#ifdef __KERNEL__
# define HZ             1500       /* Internal kernel timer frequency */
# define USER_HZ        1500             /* .. some user interfaces are in "ticks" */
# define CLOCKS_PER_SEC         (USER_HZ)       /* like times() */
#endif

#ifndef HZ
#define HZ 100
#endif

#define EXEC_PAGESIZE   4096

#ifndef NOGROUP
#define NOGROUP         (-1)
#endif

#define MAXHOSTNAMELEN  64      /* max length of hostname */

#endif

vi include/linux/jiffies.h

/*
 * The following defines establish the engineering parameters of the PLL
 * model. The HZ variable establishes the timer interrupt frequency, 100 Hz
 * for the SunOS kernel, 256 Hz for the Ultrix kernel and 1024 Hz for the
 * OSF/1 kernel. The SHIFT_HZ define expresses the same value as the
 * nearest power of two in order to avoid hardware multiply operations.
 */
#if HZ >= 12 && HZ < 24
# define SHIFT_HZ       4
#elif HZ >= 24 && HZ < 48
# define SHIFT_HZ       5
#elif HZ >= 48 && HZ < 96
# define SHIFT_HZ       6
#elif HZ >= 96 && HZ < 192
# define SHIFT_HZ       7
#elif HZ >= 192 && HZ < 384
# define SHIFT_HZ       8
#elif HZ >= 384 && HZ < 768
# define SHIFT_HZ       9
#elif HZ >= 768 && HZ < 1536
# define SHIFT_HZ       10
#elif HZ >= 1536 && HZ < 3072
# define SHIFT_HZ       11
#else
# error You lose.
#endif

make menuconfig

Processor type and features --->
[ ] Tickless System (Dynamic Ticks) (NEW)
[*] High Resolution Timer Support
Preemption Model (Preemptible Kernel (Low-Latency Desktop))
[*] Preempt The Big Kernel Lock
Timer frequency (1000 HZ)
```

Comment: Оставлю пару ссылок
https://np.reddit.com/r/kernel/comments/3waruq/linux_what_config_hz_for_optimal_responsiveness/

https://serverfault.com/questions/377947/1000-hz-linux-kernel-necessary-if-i-have-tickless-and-high-resolution-timer